# How to increase the size of a pinned array in C# dynamically?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am developing a basic POC VM with garbage collection capability. The language I am using is C#, where I am using a **pinned** byte array as the VM's memory. Is it possible to dynamically increase the size of the memory without moving it by .net GC?

The code I am using is very straightforward

```
byte[] _memory = new byte[2048];
var _gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(_memory, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var _memHandler = _gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

If I want to re-size the _memory in the code afterwards, how would I do that without unpinning it? Should I use another technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And if you think about it, it's impossible to do dependably.

Imagine a chunk of memory is set like:

[some_string][_memory][boxed_int32][some_URI]

Then it would be impossible to re-size `_memory` without moving it.

The best you could hope for was a call that would re-size it in place if possible, and not otherwise (either failing and forcing you to re-size through copy, or doing the copy when necessary and letting you know which approach worked).

So, as it is, it's unlikely to be possible, but what about catching the case where it is possible as an optimisation. What if [some_URI] had been collected in the mean-time?

Sadly (though happily really for the majority of code, including the rest of your app), this won't work as an optimisation for this relatively rare case, because there's already an optimisation for the entire memory management in that the GC will move stuff into that position if there's a gap, to reduce fragmentation. That your pinning the array makes it less efficient at moving stuff around just increases the chances that it will do so (because you've perhaps forced it to not a small bit of space before your array).

If your array is on the LOH it would be more likely that the space after it wasn't used, but then less likely that it would have been freed.

So, even though this sort of re-malloc could theoretically work sometimes, the odds of it working any given time are too small to be worth implementing.

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to re-size the _memory in the code afterwards, how would I do that without unpinning it?

There is no reliable way to do this, and no managed API whatsoever to accomplish it.  The problem is, once the memory is pinned, it can't be moved.  Resizing an array could very well require the allocation occur at a different location (since there is likely to not be a contiguous chunk of memory large enough at the current location).

As such, you'd need to unpin the memory, reallocate/resize, then create your new pinned array.  Make sure that any native code holding the memory (which would be the reason to pin in the first place) is updated to not use the previous memory location.

Answer (score 3):

In C# there is no way to re-size an array at all (whether it's pinned or not).  You can only ever create a new array of the desired size.

If you create a new array, there is no way to pin it to the location where the old array had been pinned.